# How can I get Security descriptor of kernel objects?

Tags: c++, winapi, kernel

I have the list of kernel objects that I recieved from function `NtQUeryDirectoryObject()`.

How can I get a security descriptor of this objects? I need read `DACL` of all this objects, but all attempts fail with error *"acces is denied"*.

Comment: Open each of the objects with READ_CONTROL access right and then use NtQuerySecurityObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN GetSecurityInfo() remarks:
*To read the owner, group, or DACL from the object's security descriptor, the calling process must have been granted READ_CONTROL access when the handle was opened. To get READ_CONTROL access, the caller must be the owner of the object or the object's DACL must grant the access.*

Basically as I understand DACL is zero plus access control entries. Each of these have kinda table with SID and accesses denied or granted. Now, DACL is controlled by object's owner. Owner can definitely give others control(search MSDN for appropriate API), or i think other s can also set it by call to something like SetKernelObjectSecurity(forgot params..:))..

I think it will make a difference depending on 'what' kernel object you are dealing with. Also about DACL - research it being about empty and null.